# return data based on dates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have controller that has

```
@account_info = @account_info.account_dates(params[:start_date], params[:end_date]) unless
params[:start_date].nil? || params[:end_date].nil?
```

Model has

```
self.table_name = 'UserAccounts'
scope :account_dates, -> (start_date, end_date) { where(account_date: start_date.to_date...(end_date.to_date + 1)) }
```

I have json created to display the data about account

```
accounts: [
{
name: "John"
account_date: "2016-12-27"
},
{
name: "Mike"
account_date: "2017-01-03"
},
{
name: "Jason"
account_date: "2014-01-01" 
}
]
```

start_date and end_date are optional parameters. right now if i dont pass them i get all the entries shown above which is one of the requirement. second requirement is if i just pass start_date e.g 2016-12-27 then i get the entries between start_date and todays date so i'll get 2016-12-27 and "2017-01-03" entries from json. I am new to rails. can someone help me how can i update my code for second requirement?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do this:

```
end_date = params[:end_date] || Time.now
account_info = @account_info.account_dates(params[:start_date], end_date) unless params[:start_date].nil?
```

Comment: Thanks, can you please explain me how this part is working? account_info @account_info.account_dates(params[:start_date], end_date). do you know any online stuff i can go through?